# Is it possible to apply client id/secret validation and oauth (bearer token) policies to an API in mule 4?

Tags: mule4

Can we apply two authentication policies like client ID enforcement and OAuth 2.0 to an API?

I have a requirement - if client ID enforcement is disabled then token bearer should be enabled and vice-versa.

Please let me know.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply both policies but policies don't switch automatically if one is they disabled. You have to do it manually in API Manager or you could automate it, using Anypoint Platform REST APIs or a script that invokes [Anypoint CLI](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/anypoint-platform-cli-commands#commands-for-api-manager).

Comment: Thanks @aled. Can this be done by creating 2 Proxy APIs (one for client id enforcement and another for bearer token) and applying policies?

Comment: I believe it is possible if they are different instances of the same API.